# How to query Apache Ignite using IN clause

Tags: java, ignite

I've a schema created in Apache Ignite as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------
EmpId | EmpName | HomeZip | OfficeZip| Dept |
---------------------------------------------
1     | Sam     | 98123   | 98123    |  A   |
---------------------------------------------
2     | Jack    |  98123  | 98123    |  B   |
---------------------------------------------
3     | John    |  98124  | 98123    |  A   |
---------------------------------------------
4     | Kim     | 98124   | 98123    |  C   |
---------------------------------------------
```

How can I do the followin queries:

- Find all details of employees in dept A.
- Find all details of employees whose homeZip is same as OfficeZip.

How can I do this using the SQLQuery and map the response to the Model class

```
class Employee{
  private Integer empId;
  private String empName;
  private String homeZip;
  private String officeZip;
  private String dept;
}
```

I tried querying it as follows but errors out for me:

```
//For finding out employee in list of departments
SqlQuery sql = new SqlQuery(Employee.class, "dept in (?)).setArgs(deptList);
//For finding out employee with same zip for office and home:
SqlQuery sql = new SqlQuery(Employee.class, "homeZip = officeZip");
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you just need to write couple of very straightforward SQL queries. Did you try anything? Is there a specific issue you need help with?

Comment: Yes please see the update in the question. I'm not sure if that's the correct way of writing IN clause queries. It errors out with "Failed to run map query remotely"

Comment: Please provide whole exception stack trace.

Comment: Looks like there are some issues around "IN clause" based queries. I'm looking for something similar: 
http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/SQL-IN-Operator-td779.html

Comment: Nothing changed since then. You can replace IN with JOIN though, see point 2 here: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/performance-and-debugging#sql-performance-and-usability-considerations

Comment: Thanks @ValentinKulichenko . It worked per the shared link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed the link : https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/performance-and-debugging#sql-performance-and-usability-considerations

```
    SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery(
                    "select e.* from Employee e join table(dept varchar = ?) d on e.dept = d.dept")
                   .setArgs(new Object[]{deptList.toArray()});
```