# Apache Ignite : Ignite Repository query with "IN" clause, returns no records

Tags: sql, spring-data, ignite, in-clause

I am using Apache Ignite as the back-end data store in a SpringBoot Application.
I have a requirement where I need to get all the entities whose name matches one of the names from a set of names.

Hence i am trying to get it implemented using a `@Query` configuration and a method named `findAllByName(Iterable<String> names)`as below: 
Here on the `Query`, I am trying to use the `'IN'` clause and want to pass an array of `names` as an input to the `'IN'` clause.

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "Category")
public interface CategoryRepository extends IgniteRepository<Category, Long> 
{
List<Category> findByName(String name);
@Query("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE name IN ( ? )")
Iterable<Category> findAllByName(Iterable<String> names); // this method always returns empty list .
}
```

In this the method *`findAllByName`* always returns empty list, even when `ignite` has `Categories` for which the `name` field matches the data passed in the query. 
I am unable to figure out if there is a problem with the Syntax or the query of the method signature or the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `String[] names` instead for supplying parameters.

**UPDATE:** I have just checked the source, and we don't have tests for such scenario. It means that you're on uncharted territory even if it is somehow possible to get to work.
Otherwise looks unsupported currently.

Comment: this change doesn't help : '`@Query("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE name IN ( ? )")
Iterable<Category> findAllByName(String[] names); `' this returns no records

Comment: @alamar - while this remains unsupported - what is the recommended approach to address this use case? Would you advise to go via the SQLQuery API instead of ignite repo?

Comment: @NeerajSingh getAll() of Cache API should be fine

Comment: use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/52375270/1412450

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is more specific to Spring Data Ignite feature. However, as an alternate, you can achieve it using the SqlQuery abstraction of Ignite.

You will form your query like this. I have pasted the sample below with custom sql function **inSet** that you will write. Also, the below tells how this is used in your sql.

```
IgniteCache<String, MyRecord> cache = this.ignite
    .cache(this.environment.getProperty(Cache.CACHE_NAME));

String sql = "from “my-ignite-cache”.MyRecord WHERE  
MyRecord.city=?  AND inSet(?, MyRecord.flight)"

SqlQuery<String, MyRecord> sqlQuery = new SqlQuery<>(MyRecord.class,
    sql);

sqlQuery.setArgs(MyCity, [Flight1, Flight2 ] );

QueryCursor<Entry<String, MyRecord>> resultCursor = cache.query(sqlQuery);
```

You can iterate the result cursor to do something meaningful from the extracted data.

```
resultCursor.forEach(e -> {
    MyRecord record = e.getValue();
// do something with result
});
```

Below is the Ignite [Custom Sql function](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/custom-sql-functions) which is used in the above Query - this will help in replicating the IN clause feature.

```
@QuerySqlFunction
public static boolean inSet(List<String> filterParamArgIds, String id) {
    return filterParamArgIds.contains(id);
}
```

And finally, as a reference `MyRecord` referred above can be defined something like this.

```
public class MyRecord implements Serializable {

    @QuerySqlField(name = "city", index = true)
    private String city;

    @QuerySqlField(name = "flight", index = true)
    private String flight;
}
```